# How align article publishing date on the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css

Basically I need that article publishing date (1/9/2016) lays or aligns on the bottom inside the container.  Right now the date sits just right under the text, but I need it to lay on the bottom of the container. my site is watchathletics.com

```css
.headline_container {
 width: 334px;
 height: 80px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 8px 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6; 
 background: #fff;
 
}

.headline_photo {
 width:90px;
 height:60px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-left: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
} 


.headline_text {
 position: relative;
 left: 111px;
 top: -63px;
 width: 220px;
 height: 60px;
 font-size: 13px;
 }

.headline_text a {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.top_pub_date {
  font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="headline_container">
             <div class="headline_photo"><img src=\"image.jpg"></div>
                <div class="headline_text">&bull; <a style=\"font-size:14px; line-height:105%\" href="#" class="clear_href" title=\"$top_normal_title\"> Some text hereSome text hereSome text hereSome text here </a><br/><div class="top_pub_date"> 1/9/2016 </div></div>
            </div>
```

nt increases.

Answer (score 2):

You can `absolute` position the element.

In this example I just positioned it at the right-bottom:

```css
.headline_container {
  width: 334px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6; 
  background: #fff;

}

.headline_photo {
  width:90px;
  height:60px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
} 


.headline_text {
  position: relative;
  left: 111px;
  top: -63px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.headline_text a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.top_pub_date {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline_container">
             <div class="headline_photo"><img src=\"image.jpg"></div>
                <div class="headline_text">&bull; <a style=\"font-size:14px; line-height:105%\" href="#" class="clear_href" title=\"$top_normal_title\"> Some text hereSome text hereSome text hereSome text here </a><br/><div class="top_pub_date"> 1/9/2016 </div></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dekel position: absolute solved the issue. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your class `.top_pub_date` to:

```
.top_pub_date {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

```css
.headline_container {
 width: 334px;
 height: 80px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 8px 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6; 
 background: #fff;
 
}

.headline_photo {
 width:90px;
 height:60px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-left: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
} 


.headline_text {
 position: relative;
 left: 111px;
 top: -63px;
 width: 220px;
 height: 60px;
 font-size: 13px;
 }

.headline_text a {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.top_pub_date {
  font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="headline_container">
             <div class="headline_photo"><img src=\"image.jpg"></div>
                <div class="headline_text">&bull; <a style=\"font-size:14px; line-height:105%\" href="#" class="clear_href" title=\"$top_normal_title\"> Some text hereSome text hereSome text hereSome text here </a><br/><div class="top_pub_date"> 1/9/2016 </div></div>
            </div>
```